# vb.net create tabpages and datagridview from list exported from SQL

Tags: vb.net, tabs

Just after some ideas on the best way to create additional tabpages dynamically within a tabcontrol and also to then add the relevant data on each tab with a datagridview.

The tabcontrol will always exist, but I'm not sure whether to initially create the additional tabpages first by identifying the distinct data in SQL, and then run a further script to extract the data, which then needs to be added to the datagridview, or whether I can use vb.net to create the distinct tabpages and add the data from one table, as below.

I can add another tabpage dynamically but not sure the best way to do it for a list, that is extracted from SQL.

Hope that makes sense.  Thanks

| TabCode | TabName | DataName | DataType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | One | Test Name | Text |
| 1 | One | Test Date | Date |
| 2 | Two | Test Value | Value |

I've managed to create new tabpages, but only single instances as not sure how to create them from a list extracted from SQL.  I'm then struggling to add the data to the relevant datagridview, which I envisage would be created with a name linked to the tabpage name.

Comment: Not really 100% sure what exactly your question is.  If you're able to retrieve the required query results from your database, it's simply a case of iterating the results with a loop to create the tab pages in pretty much the exact same way as when you create a single one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello.  Sorry just to clarify, I'm trying to work out the best way to reference the data from SQL.  Do I create a hidden datagridview and import the data then run the loop to create the tabpages, or would this be difficult identifying the distinct values?  Can I loop directly from the SQL data without a datagridview?  Thanks

Comment: I've sorted it by looping through a hidden datagridview, so hopefully that's the best way.